# How to get ClientID in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have 7 Check Boxes for 7 weeks and separate time picker for 7 days on the page. When a check box is checked I want to show time picker for that week day, and if it is unchecked I want to hide respective time picker

I have used following code to get this, and it is working too.

```
function Chk_WeekDay_Clicked(ctrl, week) {
    if (ctrl.checked) {
        if (week == "Monday")
            document.getElementById("<%= Tm_Monday_From.ClientID %>").style.display = "";
        else if (week == "Tuesday")
            document.getElementById("<%= Tm_Tuesday_From.ClientID %>").style.display = "";
        else if (week == "Wednesday")
            document.getElementById("<%= Tm_Wednesday_From.ClientID %>").style.display = "";
       //Rest of the days 
    }
    else{
        if (week == "Monday")
            document.getElementById("<%= Tm_Monday_From.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
        else if (week == "Tuesday")
            document.getElementById("<%= Tm_Tuesday_From.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
        else if (week == "Wednesday")
            document.getElementById("<%= Tm_Wednesday_From.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
        //Rest of the days 
    }
}
```

Chk_WeekDay_Clicked is a event handler for all week day check box. First parameter is the Clicked CheckBox control and second parameter is name of week day.

All Time picker control's name have same naming patterned as, **Tm_[WeekName]_From**

So, My question is instead of using these many if-else can I do it in couple of lines? something like code below.

```
function Chk_WeekDay_Clicked(ctrl, week) {
    //I want this controlId by using parameter. And I must get it by ClientID as I am using it on page having MasterPage.
    var controlId = "Tm_" + week + "_From";
    if (ctrl.checked) {
        document.getElementById(controlId).style.display = "";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(controlId).style.display = "none";
        }
}
```

My actual problem is how can I get Control's ClientId in a Variable. As my page using Master Page, I must use ClientID to get controls id.

So, can anyone suggest the solution for this

Comment: Can you show some html of this ?

Comment: And how have you called the function `Chk_WeekDay_Clicked` ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad <asp:CheckBox ID="Chk_Monday" runat="server" onclick="return Chk_WeekDay_Clicked(this, 'Monday');" />

Answer (score 2):

ClientID is generated by ASP.NET, They can't be created using JavaScript variable. However you can do something like this

```
function Chk_WeekDay_Clicked(ctrl, week) {

    //Since Client ID is generated by ASP.NET
    //Create a list of ids
    var controls  = {
        "monday" : "<%= Tm_Monday_From.ClientID %>",
        "tuesday" : "<%= Tm_Tuesday_From.ClientID %>",
        "wednesday" : "<%= Tm_Wednesday_From.ClientID %>",
    }

    //Fetch Control ID
    var controlId = controls[week.toLowerCase()];

    //Desired operation
    if (ctrl.checked) {
        document.getElementById(controlId).style.display = "";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(controlId).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are `passing control` itself to the function you can `directly` access `properties` of that `control`.

```
function Chk_WeekDay_Clicked(ctrl, week) {
    if (ctrl.checked) 
        ctrl.style.display = "";
    else 
        ctrl.style.display = "none";
}
```